# Has tardive dyskinesia ever "gotten better?"

Tags: neurology

I have tardive dyskinesia and my doctor said when he diagnosed me that it "might" not go away. I've heard that it's "potentially permanent." Has there ever been a recorded case where the condition has completely disappeared?

Comment: The reason this question was closed is wrong. The actual question isn't seeking medical advice.

Answer (score 3):

Tardive dyskinesia will, in many cases, get better after the offending drug is stopped.

In severe cases, it is less common to have complete remission (where the symptoms completely disappear). But it can happen [1].

[1] Vesely, C., et al. "Remission of severe tardive dyskinesia in a schizophrenic patient treated with the atypical antipsychotic substance quetiapine." International clinical psychopharmacology (2000).

Comment: Too bad I can't stop taking the offending drug...

Comment: Talk to your doctor. In many cases, you can be switched to a different medication.